# Is unique_ptr guaranteed to store nullptr after move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Is `unique_ptr` guaranteed to store `nullptr` after move?

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1{new int{23}};
std::unique_ptr<int> p2{std::move(p1)};
assert(!p1); // is this always true?
```

Comment: _Technically_ the state in which `::move` leaves an element is unspecified. I don't think there is any guarantee on the smart pointer's end either. That said, I'll leave it to the CPP experts to answer :)

Comment: Wait, never mind, yes. Release explicitly sets it to nullptr. This is guaranteed by the `unique_ptr`

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 here, p1 is null after the std::move

Comment: See any reference on [`std::unique_ptr::operator:`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator=) and [`std::unique_ptr::release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release).

Comment: just look at move semantics...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Uh, `std::move` doesn't leave elements in any particular state in any case. i.e. `(void)std::move(x)` will not modify `x` no matter what the type of `x` is. It's not `std::move` that does anything, it's the movement of the object itself (move assignment or move construction), which `std::move` *cannot* make any claims about (even claiming the behavior is unspecified is beyond its jurisdiction, so to speak).

Comment: @Mehrdad right, which is why I said "I don't think there is any guarantee on the smart pointer" immediately after, which I immediately corrected to "oh wait, it explicitly sets it to nullptr".

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, you can compare it to `nullptr` after the `move` and it is guaranteed to compare equal.

From *§20.8.1/4 [unique.ptr]*

> Additionally, `u` can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer `u2`. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>   — `u2.p` is equal to the pre-transfer `u.p`,
>   — **`u.p` is equal to `nullptr`**, and
>   ...

(the member `p` is described earlier as — *a unique pointer is an object `u` that stores a pointer to a second object `p`*)

Comment: This is clearly true after calling release(). But std::move doesn't call release(). So how does the compiler know to restore the invariant of the unique_ptr?

Comment: @mabraham `p2{std::move(p1)}` is move constructing `p2` from `p1`. That's the *requested transfer of ownership* in the text I quoted above. The move constructor implementation will make sure all the postconditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. Rephrasing: the use of the move constructor requests transfer of ownership, and that must maintain the invariant of p1. std::move just enables the use of the move constructor.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. From C++2011 Standard Section *20.7.1/4*:

> Additionally, u can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer u2. Upon completion of
>   such a transfer, the following postconditions hold [...] [the source unique_ptr] is equal to nullptr...