# How to prevent clients from passing a nullptr to a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, unique-ptr

With a constructor that expects a `std::unique_ptr`, how do you prevent clients from passing a `nullptr` effectively?

```
class Foo{
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar) :
        myBar(std::move(bar))
    {}
}
```

Could I overload the constructor with a `nullptr_t` argument and then set it as deleted to detect some `nullptr`s at compile-time?

```
Foo(nullptr_t) = delete;
```

Can I safely check for `nullptr` in the body of the constructor when I already moved it in the initialiser list? (Something tells me I can't)

```
Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar>) :
    myBar(std::move(bar))
{ 
    if(!bar)
        throw invalid_argument();
}
```

Comment: `Foo(nullptr_t) = deleted;` - Yes. Except keep in mind that only stops `nullptr`, not a null pointer.

Comment: That will catch `Foo{nullptr}`, but not `Foo{std::unique_ptr<Bar>{}}`.

Comment: gcc has [nonnull](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute and will perform some static analysis based on it. I'm not sure how well this works in C++ though.

Comment: @Banthar quite interesting, but I'm on MSVC.

Comment: @aschepler right. Didn't think about that. At least it will filter some blatant misuse, and it doesn't really have any drawbacks whatsoever unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: If a `nullptr` is not an acceptable argument value, I would suggest that a `unique_ptr` is not the correct parameter type.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Interesting point. A reference would probably suffice, but a `unique_ptr` ensures that no more than exactly one object has ownership of `Bar`. It encourages clients to pass a `unique_ptr` created via `make_unique`, making it harder to misuse the interface. It probably comes down to personal preference though.

Comment: @iFreilicht: No, I wouldn't suggest a reference either. I would suggest a class which exactly fits the requirements you need. Normally, I would just suggest simply storing a Bar object by value. But I assume you've already considered that option and determined that it doesn't fit your requirements. (right?) In that case, it seems like what you need is a class which ensures that a unique Bar object exists within it. It might just be a wrapper class around a `unique_ptr<Bar>` that doesn't allow the possibility of a null `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley funnily enough, that's exactly what I'm doing with the class `Foo`, wrapping `unique_ptr` for my special needs. The problem with passing an object by value is that my `Bar`s are quite big. EDIT: my `Foo` constructor should probably just emulate the `Bar` constructor or act as a forwarder, just like `make_unique` does.

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't think you should take in a unique_ptr. Instead, you should overload `Foo` with same constructors which your `Bar` class has, and forward them to the `unique_ptr` within the constructor. The `unique_ptr` should not be visible to the outside. EDIT: I see you edited your comment to say exactly what I was about to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would combine both approaches:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar) :
        myBar(std::move(bar))
    {
        if(!myBar)  // check myBar, not bar
            throw invalid_argument();
    }
    Foo(nullptr_t) = delete;
}
```

The deleted constructor will prevent someone from doing `Foo{nullptr}` but it won't prevent `Foo{std::unique_ptr<Bar>{}}`, so you need the check within the constructor body as well.

However, you cannot check the argument `bar` after `move`ing it, that check will [always fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24061876/241631). Check the data member (`myBar`) that you moved the `unique_ptr` into.

Comment: Oh thanks! That's one of those really pesky mistakes. Could you say anything about exception safety? I mean what happens when `invalid_argument` is thrown? Then we would've already moved `bar`, so there is not even weak exception safety given, right?

Comment: @iFreilicht You only throw if `bar` contains `nullptr`, there's no resource to leak, so I'm not sure what you mean by exception safety in this case.

Comment: @Praetorian, How do I suppose to catch this exception? If I just do `try { f = Foo( bar ) } catch( const std::invalid_argument& ia ) { do smth }` then `f` is out of scope. Does this solution mean that I am not supposed to catch this exception?

Answer (score 3):

Constructors can be declared as deleted using `= delete`:

```
Foo(nullptr_t) = delete;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly remove the `nullptr_t` constructor, but that will not catch `NULL` or empty `std::unique_ptr` instances.  You should validate the input inside the constructor to handle that latter case:

```
class Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> myBar;

    Foo(nullptr_t) = delete;

    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar) :
        myBar(std::move(bar))
    {
        if (myBar == nullptr)
            throw invalid_argument();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If polymorphic behaviour isn't needed (i.e. you never subclass `Bar`) then simply pass `Bar` by value to the `Foo` ctor. Otherwise, if you still need to pass it by pointer for some reason, I think there is no 100% foolproof solution. You may try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct stricter_unique_ptr: std::unique_ptr<T> {

    // Always initialize with new object
    template<typename... A>
    stricter_unique_ptr(A&&... a):
        std::unique_ptr<T>{new T{std::forward<A>(a)...}}
    {}

    // Allow downcasting
    template<typename U>
    stricter_unique_ptr(stricter_unique_ptr<U> &&u):
        std::unique_ptr<T>{std::move(u)}
    {}

private:

    // Don't I forget to hide anything?
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::operator =;
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::release;
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::reset;
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::swap;

};

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived: Base {
    Derived(int, float) {}
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(stricter_unique_ptr<Base> base): base{std::move(base)} {
        std::cout << this->base.get() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo{stricter_unique_ptr<Derived>{42, 3.14}}; // That's it

    stricter_unique_ptr<Derived> p{42, 3.14};
    Foo foo1{std::move(p)}; // This is OK
    Foo foo2{std::move(p)}; // But still possible to cheat
}
```

Comment: Passing `Bar` by value is not really an option as it is too large. Have a look at [these comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091876/how-to-prevent-clients-from-passing-a-nullptr-to-a-constructor/24092325#comment37158421_24091876) where we came to the conclusion that a simple forwarder is the best solution in my case. I do in fact not need polymorphic behaviour and ended up using `std::forward` just like you.