# Singly linked list with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, linked-list, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) to create a singly linked list. Here is an example of a singly linked list with raw pointer.

```cpp
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next = nullptr;
  Node(int data) : data{data}, next{nullptr} {}
  ~Node() { std::cout << "Destroy node with data: " << data << '\n'; }
};

void print_list(Node *head) {
  while (head != nullptr) {
    cout << head->data << " --> ";
    head = head->next;
  }
  cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}

void insert(Node *&head, int data) {
  Node *new_node = new Node{data};
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Node *head = nullptr;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    insert(head, i);
  }
  print_list(head);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
4 --> 3 --> 2 --> 1 --> 0 --> nullptr
```

Apparently there is memory leak in the above code (destructor is not called). Now I want to use smart pointer to achieve the same thing:

```cpp
struct Node {
  int data = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
  Node(int data) : data{data}, next{nullptr} {}
  ~Node() { std::cout << "Destroy node with data: " << data << '\n'; }
};

void print_list(std::unique_ptr<Node> head) {
  while (head != nullptr) {
    std::cout << head->data << " --> ";
    head = std::move(head->next);
  }
  std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}

void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> &&head, int data) {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node{std::make_unique<Node>(data)};
  new_node->next = std::move(head);
  head = std::move(new_node);
}

// g++ -std=c++17 -Wall 2_1.cpp && ./a.out
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> head{nullptr};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    insert(std::move(head), i);
  }
  print_list(std::move(head));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
4 --> Destroy node with data: 4
3 --> Destroy node with data: 3
2 --> Destroy node with data: 2
1 --> Destroy node with data: 1
0 --> Destroy node with data: 0
nullptr
```

We can observe that the life time of `new_node` ends when `insert()` returns. I would like to know if it's possible to use smart pointers to achieve singly linked list and retains the functions interface as above.

Comment: Why did you change the `head` parameter to `insert()` from an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference?

Comment: *"We can observe that the life time of `new_node` ends when `insert()` returns."* -- true, but not as significant as you seem to think. When `insert()` returns, `new_node` should be managing a null pointer, so the end of its lifetime has no observable effect. (You could stick a line like `std::cout << "new_node.get() == " << new_node.get() << "\n";` at the end if `insert()` to verify this.)

Comment: Related: [Is unique_ptr guaranteed to store nullptr after move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061767/)

Comment: "I am trying to use smart pointers (std::unique_ptr) to create a singly linked list." You don't want this, unless your goal is to convince yourself that you don't want this

Comment: @n.m. You should explain why that is. Insert a million nodes and observe your list explode during destruction.

Comment: @j6t right. You need to write your own copy ctor and assignment, you need to write your own move ctor and assignment, you need to write your own dtor because of the recursive destruction, *and* the iterators must use raw pointers so the uniqueness of `next` is simply a lie. There is no win absolutely anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, there is a problem with your `print_list` implementation(<del>for both version</del> for `unique_ptr` only). With your `print_list`, every time you assign `head` with a different `uniq_ptr`, you are actually deallocating the only `Node` in `head`, which is not desired. Instead, in your `print_list`, you should first create a temporary pointer pointing to `head`, then only iterate on the temporary pointer.

---

Now onto your `unique_ptr` version, you don't have to pass a `unique_ptr`  as rvalue reference, you can also pass it as lvalue reference. Instead, your function signature would probably look like:

```cpp
void print_list(const std::unique_ptr<Node>& head);
void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> &head, int data);
```

This allow you to call them without using `std::move` in your `main`.

---

Now on to definitions. For your insertion, what you have is you first create a new `Node` with the given value, then you assign the old `head` to new node's `next`, and make the new node as the new `head`:

```cpp
void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> &head, int data)
{
    // Use `auto` to avoid typing `....<Node>` twice
    auto new_node = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
    new_node->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(new_node);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also add one more parameter to `Node`'s constructor:

```cpp
Node(int data, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& next = nullptr) 
: data{data}, next{std::move(next)}
{}
```

Now you can simply create `new_node` like:

```cpp
void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> &head, int data)
{
    // No need to assign `Node::next` separately
    auto new_node = std::make_unique<Node>(data, std::move(head));
    head = std::move(new_node);
}
```

Or even assign the new node to `head` directly:

```cpp
void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> &head, int data)
{
    head = std::make_unique<Node>(data, std::move(head));
}
```

---

For `print_list`, we should first create a temporary pointer that points to the underlying object of `head`, then iterate the list by assigning the temporary pointer to its next object's underlying object:

```cpp
void print_list(const std::unique_ptr<Node>& head)
{
    // Create a pointing to the underlying object
    // You can use `.get()` to get the underlying pointer
    auto current = head.get();

    // No need to explicit compare pointer types to `nullptr`
    while (current) {
        std::cout << current->data << " --> ";
        // Make `current` point to the next underlying object
        current = current->next.get();
    }
    std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

---

Now your main would look like:

```cpp
int main(int, char *[]) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        insert(head, i);
    }
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3M57vW5zs)

Comment: I'd even suggest that the signature should look like `void print_list(const Node& head)`, assuming we don't try to encapsulate the `Node` further into a dedicated `LinkedList` class. `print_list` doesn't have any obvious reason to care about the ownership structure of the node it's printing.

Comment: @NathanPierson I agree. It does alternate the function call slightly however, so not sure if it's desired for OP

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Thanks for the detailed answer. There is one thing kind of intriguing me is that in the raw pointer version of `print_list`, the head is actually not lost. I can call `print_list(head);` twice in a row and they both print the complete list. See this link: https://godbolt.org/z/hP8fbGEK1

Comment: Yeah, because raw pointers don't have ownership over the things they point to. When `head` is a pointer and you write `head = head->next;`, nothing much happens to whatever used to be pointed to by `head->next`. When you do `head = std::move(head->next);` and `head` is a `unique_ptr`, then you have to look at what happens with `unique_ptr`'s move-assignment operation to see what happens to `head->next`.

Comment: ok, i think i understand what happens. In the raw pointer version of `void print_list(Node *head)`, `head` is a pass-by-value pointer. `head` is indeed modified in `print_list` but not modified in `main`. However, if changing to `void print_list(Node *&head)`, now `head` is a pass-by-reference pointer, so whatever happens to `head` in `print_list` will also change `head` in `main`.

Comment: @LionLai You are correct. I have misspoken originally. As you said `print_list(Node*)` passes `head` by copy, so the original `head` does not change. But like ***@NathanPierson*** said, when you reassign the `unique_ptr`, it will deallocate the original object in it first.